# Regex to find strings not encapsulated with __("")

Tags: regex, phpstorm, regex-negation

I am trying to find any instance of a string in our code that needs to be sent to the __() function.

I have the following regex:

```
 (\[|__\()[\'\"][\w\s\\\:]+[\'\"]
```

that matches:

```
 ['valid string'
 ["valid::str::ing"
 __('valid\String'
 __(" v a l i d s t r i n g "
```

but not:

```
 'hel\lo there '
 "he::he"
```

I need it to reverse the match.  I have tried various methods to negate the ([|__() section but have not had any success.

How can I write the the expression to match the strings that are NOT preceded by the [ or __(?

Thank you.

Comment: It's not enough to say you have a "regex", you have to indicate what tool or language you're using. Some support a negative lookbehind notation, `(?<!...)`, that can do what you want, but some don't, and even of those that do, the details vary somewhat.

Comment: Does nastiness like `'hey it\'s an unexpected \''` need to be handled too?

Comment: @ruakh - sorry, the expression will be executed in PHPStorm.

Comment: @Wrikken - yes, but I am less concerned with the string details than with getting the first part working.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use a negative lookbehind. Please see:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: This is not an answer.  If you need more information before you can propose a solution, ask for it in a comment like [ruakh did](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18197671/regex-to-find-strings-not-encapsulated-with#comment26669287_18197671).  Vague hints like this are incompatible with SO's [philosophy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
/([^\[\(]|[^\_]\(|[^\_]_\()[\'\"][\w\s\\\:]+[\'\"]/
```

matches strings with `'` or `"`, that don't have a `[` or a `(` in front,
but allows `(` if it's not a `_` in front of it,
and also allows `_(` if there isn't a 2nd `_` in front of it